# f# functions name hiding type casting

Tags: f#

I was messing with the f#Koans and this will run (2*2 = 2). From my understanding, when within the scope of quadruple, the 'double' cast is hidden by the local function. Once out, I don't get a compiler error because I get back my 'cast'?

```
  let NestingFunctions() =
        let quadruple x =    
            let double x =
                x * 2

            double(double(x))

        let result = quadruple 4
        let resultDouble =  double 2
        AssertEquality resultDouble 2
```

Comment: You shouldn't give a function a name that's already being used by F#.

Comment: Yes, like you say. Within quadruple 'double' is your function, outside it's the double operator again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may look like casting, it actually isn't. The casting operators are `:>` and `:?>`, these cannot be overridden. With the casting operators, the types have to be compatible.

The `double` function is just that, a function, and works on any object that implements the explicit casting operator (`op_Explicit`). In F#, we call this *to convert* a value to double.

But your question is about scope. If you create a function that hides a global function, you can still get that back into scope by using `global.` as a prefix. Though as others already said, certain built-in functions shouldn't be shadowed unless there's a good reason for it.

```cs
let NestingFunctions() =
    let quadruple x =  
        let double x =
            x * 2

        // FQN (fully qualified) works
        let bar = global.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators.double 42  
        // or in this case, just qualify with the module also works
        let xx = ExtraTopLevelOperators.double 42

        // these both call your self-defined 'double' function
        double(double(x))

    // from here, since we outdented, function 'double' is not in scope anymore
    let result = quadruple 4
    let resultDouble =  double 2  // this is the built-in function
    ()
```